# Reading a row of data from the database and store it into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to read data from the SQL Server database and store it into an array.

First, I have to fetch each row and store it into a two-dimensional array.

```
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_Subjects WHERE USN IN(SELECT USN FROM tbl_Student WHERE Semester='" + DropDownList1.Text + "')");
            SqlDataReader rs;
            rs = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rs.Read())
            {
                for (int k = 1; k < 10; k++)
                {
                    g = k - 1;
                    num = rs[0].ToString();
                    read[g] = Convert.ToInt32(num);

                }
```

This is what I've done so far. I don't know how I could assign it to a 2D Array directly. Hence making use of a Single-Dimensional Array and thought I can copy it later.

EDIT:

I have followed the steps suggested by Hari Prasad,

```
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_Subjects WHERE USN IN(SELECT USN FROM tbl_Student WHERE Semester='" + DropDownList1.Text + "')",con);
            SqlDataReader rs;
            rs = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rs.Read())
            {
                int j = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < rs.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    arr[i, j] = int.Parse(rs.GetString(0));
                }


            }
            con.Close();
            rs.Close();
```

After this I am getting a FormatException. "Input String was not in a correct format."

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

A two dimension array can be created using `new int[5,5]`, but point to note we should know size in advance.  In this case, unfortunately, reader doesn't provide rows count in advance.

To answer your question *" I don't know how I could assign it to a 2D Array directly"*

```
//Declare 2d array
int[,] x = new int[5][rs.FieldCount]; // 
int i=0;

for( int index = 0; index < rs.FieldCount; index ++ )
{
    int validInt;

    if(int.TryParse(rs.GetString(index), out validInt)
    {
        // usage
        x[i,index] = validInt;
    }
    else { x[i,index] = -1; //default value
    } 
}
```

Instead of 2D array (above approach), I would suggest use `DataTable` it is pretty simple.

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Load(rs);
```

Now you have all your Data in `DataTable`

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
     foreach (DataColumn col in myTopTenData.Columns)
     {
         Console.Write(row[col].ToString());       
     }
}
```

Comment: After following your first approach, Im getting a FormatException.

Comment: Which line are you getting exception?

Comment: arr[i, j] = int.Parse(rs.GetString(0));

This one

Comment: Are you sure, Your data contains only integers?

Comment: Updated answer to validate input.